# If $bc+qr=ca+rp=ab+pq=-1$ then show that $\begin{vmatrix} ap & p & a \\ bq & q & b \\ cr & r & c \\ \end{vmatrix}=0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant, matrix-equations

If $bc+qr=ca+rp=ab+pq=-1$ then show that
$\begin{vmatrix} 
ap & \color{red} {p} & a \\
bq & q & b \\
cr & r & c \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=0 $
**Try**

we are given that $1 + b c + q r = 0$
$ 1 + c a + p r = 0$
$1+ab+pq=0$

The determinant in the question involves a column consisting the elements ap, bq and cr So multipying (1),(2) and (3) by ap bq and cr respectively we get
$ap+abcp+apqr=0$
$b q + a b c q + b p q r = 0$
$c r + a b c r + c p q r = 0$
Since abc and pqr occur in all the three equations putting $abc= x$ and $pqr=y$ we get
$a p + p x + a y = 0$
$bq+qx+\color{red}{b} y=0$
$cr+rx+cy=0$
Now, since there are only two variable and three equations hence to have a solution one of the equation must be a linear combination of the other hence the coefficient matrix is linearly dependent i.e. the coefficient determinant is zero.
But the book I am reading has introduced the problem before it discusses solving technique of system of linear equation. So, I wonder if there is any other way to look at this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly suspect a typo somewhere. In this form it is not true.

Comment: Oh sorry... There is a typo let me correct with your permission. The typo is written in red. (+1) for your observation and patience without down voting.

Comment: @Math-Learner I found the typo and edited my answer.

Comment: Nice approach in your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By direct computations,
\begin{align*} \begin{vmatrix} ap & p & a \\ bq & q & b \\ cr & r & c \\ \end{vmatrix} &= apqc-aprb-bqpc+bqra+crpb-crqa\\ &=ac(pq-rq)+ab(rq-rp)+bc(rp-pq)\\ &=(-1-rp)(pq-rq)+(-1-pq)(rq-rp)+(-1-rq)(pr-pq)\\ &=rq-pq+rp-rq+pq-pr +rprq-rppq+rppq-rqqp+rqpq-rqpr\\
&=0 \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I found a counterexample. Let
$$
(a,b,c,p,q,r)=(1,1,-1,-2,1,0).
$$
Then the equations are satisfied, i.e., we have
$$bc+qr=ca+rp=ab+pq=-1,$$
but the determinant of the matrix is $3$. Indeed,
$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} =3.
$$

Edit: The corrected question can be answered by a direct computation. No need of further linear algebra. The formula for the $3\times 3$ determinant is also called [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

Comment: I'm really sorry for my typo. But thanks a lot for your kind effort.